# Powershell ActiveSync Object (Child Object) Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, migration, exchange-server, activesync

I am migrating some users cross-domain with the admt tool, but I have the problem that we have many Active Sync device users. These the ADMT cannot move, as you will know. I have found several ways to delete the child object and move the user, but I'd like to keep the child object and reattach it to the user after the move. I cannot seem to find a solution for this and I'd rather not tell several hundred people to reactivate their phones. I'd love a Powershell solution, but I'll happily accept any other aproach.

Thanks all.

Comment: [power hell](http://provoketive.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/fires_of_hell.jpg)?

Comment: Have you confirmed that Exchange won't recreate the object for you if you simply remove it and move the user?

Comment: Yes, I did. It will be recreated, if the user reactivates the devices, but not by itself. At least it didn't for several hours.